# tor middle node can't connect to private tor authority server

Tags: networking, tor

We are a group of uni students and we're currently developing a project involving the creation of a private tor network.
So far we have created 2 server authorities successfully and we want to create a middle node to check if the consensus can be generated, but we have a problem that we cannot solve and we seem to not find any documentation about:

```
Nov 21 18:17:34.000 [warn] Bad v3 identity digest 'v3ident=8ExA7smGhHOiDwEttS04pkINWRh72YBMJB7XOMaF7ww' on DirAuthority line
Nov 21 18:17:34.000 [warn] Bad v3 identity digest 'v3ident=3i+SLxtN6rKnEjLVBLy23BrX9e9YrqrMKdFYSaUShGc' on DirAuthority line
```

those 2 lines are from the middle node's log file, and refer to the two identity servers that we have specified in the torrc file of the middle node, the mentioned file is:

```
UseDefaultFallbackDirs 0
DirAuthority alejandro orport=6969 v3ident=8ExA7smGhHOiDwEttS04pkINWRh72YBMJB7XOMaF7ww 172.31.22.112:9050 C71F 48D4 36BC E2BD FD74 521A F6DF F76F 1805 CF6E
DirAuthority marti orport=6969 v3ident=3i+SLxtN6rKnEjLVBLy23BrX9e9YrqrMKdFYSaUShGc 172.31.25.34:9050 23D2 7887 9F7C E57C 6ABC 60B7 6F9F F662 AF4F 5425
DirAllowPrivateAddresses 1
TestingTorNetwork 1
ExtendAllowPrivateAddresses 1
EnforceDistinctSubnets 0
AssumeReachable 1
ORPort 172.31.20.85:6969
DirPort 172.31.20.85:9050
```

All the elements of the tor network are inside a private network and we have tested the connectivity between the machines.

Comment: What is the exact question, please?

Comment: What could be causing the bad v3 identity digestion error, the fingerprints are correct.